# Brightway2 Excel Database Import Problem .write_database() ecoinvent

Tags: excel, brightway

First of all, I am pretty new to bw2 and LCAs in general, so please be understanding.

I currently work on a tool which exports the exchanges of an ecoinvent activity to an excel-sheet. 
Within the excel-sheet, I would like to change amounts and add new or delete exchanges.  After that, my plan was to use this excel-sheet as a database for a LCA.

I have two questions:

1) At the moment a have an excel-sheet with an activity and its exchanges ready to load into the jupyter notebook. I've used the "excel_importer_example" structure of maxkoslowski's "Brightway2_Intro". It works fine until I have to use ".write_database()". Somehow it won't work. I get a error message which does not help me at all:

```
*InvalidExchange                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-0d0d7c5cd566> in <module>
----> 1 imp.write_database() #hier das Problem: Database wird nicht gespeichert, obwohl Datei in Zeile drüber gefunden wird
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\excel.py in write_database(self, **kwargs)
    257         """Same as base ``write_database`` method, but ``activate_parameters`` is True by default."""
    258         kwargs['activate_parameters'] = kwargs.get('activate_parameters', True)
--> 259         super(ExcelImporter, self).write_database(**kwargs)
    260 
    261     def get_activity(self, sn, ws):
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py in write_database(self, data, delete_existing, backend, activate_parameters, **kwargs)
    238 
    239         existing.update(data)
--> 240         db.write(existing)
    241 
    242         if activate_parameters:
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\wrapt\wrappers.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    604                 return self._self_wrapper(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
    605 
--> 606             return self._self_wrapper(self.__wrapped__, self._self_instance,
    607                     args, kwargs)
    608 
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py in writable_project(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs)
    354     if projects.read_only:
    355         raise ReadOnlyProject(READ_ONLY_PROJECT)
--> 356     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\peewee\database.py in write(self, data, process)
    258         if data:
    259             try:
--> 260                 self._efficient_write_many_data(data)
    261             except:
    262                 # Purge all data from database, then reraise
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\peewee\database.py in _efficient_write_many_data(self, data, indices)
    202 
    203             for index, (key, ds) in enumerate(data.items()):
--> 204                 exchanges, activities = self._efficient_write_dataset(
    205                     index, key, ds, exchanges, activities
    206                 )
~\Miniconda3\envs\tomaten\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\peewee\database.py in _efficient_write_dataset(self, index, key, ds, exchanges, activities)
    154         for exchange in ds.get('exchanges', []):
    155             if 'input' not in exchange or 'amount' not in exchange:
--> 156                 raise InvalidExchange
    157             if 'type' not in exchange:
    158                 raise UntypedExchange
InvalidExchange:
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

2) Is it even likely that my plan will work out? The next problem I've read about is that unlinked exchanges seem to be a big problem and all of mine are unlinked atm.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have unlinked exchanges, you **can't import the database**!

Brightway is fundamentally a framework for conducting matrix based calculations. To correctly build matrices, for every data point we need to know three things: the row, the column, and the number to insert.

In the error you provided, at the very end, you see the following:

```
    155             if 'input' not in exchange or 'amount' not in exchange:
--> 156                 raise InvalidExchange
```

This is not terribly informative, but you can see here that either `input` (which would be the row; column is `output`) or `amount` (which would be the number) is missing. As you stated later on that "all of mine are unlinked," my guess is that the field `input` is the culprit.

If your exchanges are unlinked, then we have data points with numbers, and we know the column indices, but don't know the rows. We can't use them to build matrices, and so an error is raised. To fix this, we need to tell the software how to find the correct row.

The Brightway library `bw2io` uses "strategies" to do this linking. Because we support multiple file formats and mental models, there is no single way to do things. Data IO in Brightway is a big subject, but it is covered in the documentation. There are a number of [example notebooks](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/notebooks.html#importing-data-example-notebooks) on how to link data, and a section in the documentation on [importing and exporting](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/intro.html#importing-and-exporting).